# Как сделать структуру проекта?

Tags: java, desktop

Как бы вот это чудо класс Window.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
class Window extends javax.swing.JFrame {
        JButton button = new JButton("Button");
         Window() {
                Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
                setSize(dim.width,dim.height);
                setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                Window run = new Window();
                run.setVisible(true);

        }
}
```

Нужно сделать что бы `super("title");` был в другом классе super.java
Возможно ли такое сделать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Круто!!! А что вообще нужно сделать вызовом этого супер метода? У вашего класса нет статического метода `super(String)` насколько я вижу. Да и не может быть, т.к. `super` - зарезервированное слово.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделать такое невозможно (я про метод `super`)

Ответ на вопрос "Как сделать структуру проекта?"
Структура проекта зависит от самого проекта Вам необходимо разбить проект на блоки можно так написать "главные части" это могут быть основные функции проекта

Например проект которые выводит на экран информацию о животных
Сам проект называется Information_about_anumal (например)
Необходимо разбить животных на 2 типа
Например передвигается по воде/земле/воздуху (в данном случае 3 типа у Вас может быть и 4)
после необходимо разбить к примеру животных которые умеют передвигаться по воде (собаки/рыбы)
Тут немного опечатка животные имеется ввиду рыбы/животные/птицы
И после этого разбивать к примеру собак на разные типа порода или цвет(если предусмотрена такая возможность)
Надеюсь тут всё понятно есть проект берёшь основные методы которые будут использоваться в готовом проекте и разбиваешь их на блоки